# My SQL query does not return the expected

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have this mySQL query:

```
SELECT e.*, p.descricao descricao_produto, s.estado estado_descricao, Max(i.data_inspecao) DataUltimaInspecao
            FROM extintores e
            INNER JOIN extintores_produto p ON p.id = e.produto
            LEFT JOIN extintores_inspecao i ON i.ID_sst_extintores = e.id
            LEFT JOIN extintores_estado s ON s.id = e.ID_sst_extintores_estado
            WHERE (e.apagado = 0 AND i.apagado = 0) GROUP BY e.numero ORDER BY e.numero
```

My ***extintores(e)*** table has this registers:

| id | numero | numero_chassi |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 295 | 79 | 00047 |
| 148 | 79 | 421 |

My ***extintores_inspecao(i)*** table has this registers:

| id | id_extintores | data_inspecao |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5954 | 295 | 2021-03-14 |
| 4816 | 148 | 2018-01-26 |
| 5286 | 148 | 2019-02-13 |
| 5526 | 148 | 2020-02-21 |

When I run the query, I get this result:

| id | numero | data_inspecao |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 148 | 79 | 2021-03-14 |

But I want that it returns me:

| id | numero | data_inspecao |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 295 | 79 | 2021-03-14 |

Comment: Partial grouping may produce strange output. Make your query correct - each output column must be either a part of GROUP BY expression or an argument of aggregate function..

Comment: Could you be more specific? What I have to change in the query? The line "LEFT JOIN extintores_inspecao i ON i.ID_sst_extintores = e.id" does not guarantee the  column correspondance between both tables?

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Read about `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode. If you enable it your query will fail due to its incorrectness.